# Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu: "Can't load driver file apr_dbd_oracle.so"

Tags: linux, oracle, apache, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04. I have an application running in Wildfly 10.1.0 and am trying to use Apache 2.4 to force the user to log in when they browse to the app URL. I have got this working on a Windows environment and was hoping it would be as simple as copying my Apache config files over to the Ubuntu box, but it's not.

I added the line below to httpd.conf

```
Include conf/extra/dbd.conf
```

Contents of conf/extra/dbd.conf:

```
DBDriver oracle
DBDParams user=xx;pass=yy;server=zz
DBDMin  2
DBDKeep 4
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300
```

I then tried to restart Apache using the command:

```
sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

I get the message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/dbd.conf
Can't load driver file apr_dbd_oracle.so
```

I followed [this](http://qiita.com/tkprof/items/5d77a97734349da64c2c) tutorial on how to build the file apr_dbd_oracle.so. I have attempted to verify that apr_dbd_oracle.so was built properly by running the command:

```
ldd /usr/local/apr/lib/apr-util-1/apr_dbd_oracle.so
```

Which produces output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2d3f6000)
libclntsh.so.11.1 => /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00007f92d4b0e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f92d48d7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f92d4510000)
libnnz11.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib/libnnz11.so (0x00007f92d4148000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f92d3f44000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f92d3c39000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f92d3a20000)
libaio.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f92d381e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000561dd2f8b000)
```

I'm not a Linux expert but I suspect that if the .so file was corrupt then ldd would not produce this output. I conclude from this that apr_dbd_oracle.so works but Apache can't find it. I have tried copying the file to various locations, both by duplicating the file and creating symbolic links. I have also tried Googling where Apache looks for the file but no luck.

Can anyone clarify the directory that Apache expects the file apr_dbd_oracle.so to be in? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved my own problem. Restart it without typing sudo, i.e.: /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our conversation earlier:

Configuration of shared libraries for root access is different to the logged in user.

Try executing without sudo to see if it's a configuration issue.